# Pathos multiprocessing pool CPickle error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

When i tried to run the following code:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
def function1(x,y):
    print x
    print y
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(5)
    pool.map(function1, list1, list2)
```

It gets the followwing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    pool.map(function1, list1, list2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 136, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Isn't pathos.multiprocessing is designed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author.  When I try your code, I don't get an error.  However,  if you are seeing a `CPickle.PicklingError`, I'm guessing you have an issue with your install of `multiprocess`.  You are on windows, so do you have a C compiler?  You need one for `multiprocess` to get a full install of `multiprocess`.

Comment: FYI, when the install is bad, `multiprocess` defaults to the original pickler.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing a C compiler. Thanks for your help!