# Python pathos multiprocessing CPickle error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pathos

The following code:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
def function1(x,y):
    print x
    print y
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(5)
    pool.map(function1, list1, list2)
```

It gets the followwing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    pool.map(function1, list1, list2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 136, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Isn't pathos.multiprocessing is designed to solve this problem?

Comment: The code works well. Please tell us more details.

Comment: @McGrady: That's exactly what i got from running the code. I'm using Windows 10 and i've already tried CMDer,CMD but still that error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pathos multiprocessing pool CPickle error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094924/pathos-multiprocessing-pool-cpickle-error)

Comment: I answered your original posting of the above question.